# Unable to return value from inside a function

Tags: jquery, variables, return-value

This function is not letting me to pass data outside the function. 
It returns the correct data, but whenever i try to add it to an array or similar outside the function, it will not return anything. 
I am aware of some redundant json parse's and stringifies, but please ignore that. Ive tried setting global variables without any luck.

```
var item.jid = 342323; //example
p = connection.vCard.get(item.jid);   

p.done(function(vCard) {
    var json = JSON.stringify(vCard);
    var json = $.parseJSON(json);

    $(json).each(function(item,val) {
        $.each(val,function(k,v) {
            var json2 = JSON.stringify(v);
            var obj = JSON.parse(json2);
            var what = obj.BINVAL;

            if(what != undefined) {
                var bgimg = what;   
                bgimg = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+bgimg;
                //console.log(bgimg); //This returns correct data, but only from within this each loop.
                //return bgimg; //this does not return anything
                //arr.push(bgimg);//this does not push anything to array
                //console.log(item.jid); //does not return global var
            }
        });
    });           
});
```

***EDIT***
Heres the function im trying to pull of (with changes from romy's answer) for further clarification: I am building a contactroster with avatars.

```
var bgimg=null;
var arr = new Array();
function getAvatar(vCard) {
            var json = JSON.stringify(vCard);
            var json = $.parseJSON(json);
                $(json).each(function(item,val){
                    $.each(val,function(k,v){
                        var json2 = JSON.stringify(v);
                        var obj = JSON.parse(json2);
                        var what = obj.BINVAL;
                            if(what != undefined){
                                bgimg = what;   
                                bgimg = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+bgimg;
                                arr.push(bgimg);
                                //console.log(bgimg); //This returns correct data.
                            }

                    }); 
                });
         };

function getRoster(){

connection.roster.requestRoster(function(roster){
   var items = roster.getItems();
   for( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ){
        var arr = new Array();
        var item = items[i];
        var thejid = item.jid;
        var thename = item.name;
        arr.push(thejid);
        arr.push(thename);
        p = $.Deferred();
        p = connection.vCard.get(item.jid);   
            p.done(function(vCard) {
                getAvatar(vCard);
            });
       p.resolve();
       console.log(arr);
var theavatar = //This would return whatever the deferred function would throw me. 

        $('.sidebar-nav').append("<li class='contacts'><div id='"+thejid+"' class='avatar' src='"+theavatar+"'></div><a href='#' class='"+thejid+"'>"+thename+"</a></li>");

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in async/deferred execution mode.

I dont see any benefit ( it won't work either) to return as you did :

[image]

[You can use global variable if you want](http://jsbin.com/tiqofaqufo/1/edit?html,js,output) :

```
var d =  $.Deferred();

var myResult=null;

d.done(function (a){ myResult=a;}) .done(function (){ alert(window["myResult"])})


d.resolve(1); //will alert "1"
```

but I'd prefer :

```
var d =  $.Deferred();


function doWhatever(x)
{
  //do wtf you want
  alert(x)
}

var myResult=null;

d.done(function (a){ doWhatever(a)});


d.resolve(1);
```

http://jsbin.com/potula/1/edit

Comment: Hey Royi, thanks for taking the time to help, i really really appreciate it!
and you are right, it is in deferred mode. Using your logic i am able to trigger an alert showing the right data. however, im still not able to actually pass the data into anything usable like an array or variable. 

Ive ended up storing the data in localstorage and grabbing it from there. however that feels so hacky.

i find deferred to be pretty tough to understand, i might find another library that does it in a more straight-forward manor.

Comment: "_im still not able to actually pass the data into anything usable like an array or variable_"----- my first sample DOES pass data to a variable. look at myResult.

Comment: Im at a loss, sorry, the way it looks to me is that you pass that data via the resolve() function.. ive updated my code to the full monty, so you can have a look if you have time =)

Comment: resolve just ignites the whole chain . you can ignore it. my defered object wont call `done` unless someone says something is `done` that's all what `resolve` do. you dont have it becuase the API which you're using ( connection.vCard.get(item.jid); ) calls `resolve` internally. am I clear ?

Comment: ahh, yeah. i see that now. ouch...  do you think theres any way to pull it off?
Regardless, thanks a bunch for your time :)

Comment: What do you mean by pull it off ? what's wrong with what you have now ? ( in my answer). don't try to complicate things. someone calls your `done` function. you have your own code inside it. great. you wanted to know how you can pull the result to a outside variable : I showed you.